# In Revelation 12:16, what does the phrase “the earth opened its mouth” mean?

Tags: revelation, authorial-intent

In Revelation 12 the serpent opens its mouth to sweep away the woman, but the earth protects her by opening its mouth.

> **[Revelation 12:15-17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2012:15-17&version=NASB)** (NASB)
>   <sup>**15**</sup> And the serpent poured water like a river out of his mouth after the woman, so that he might cause her to be swept away with the flood. <sup>**16**</sup> But the earth helped the woman, and the earth opened its mouth and drank up the river which the dragon poured out of his mouth. <sup>**17**</sup>  So the dragon was enraged with the woman, and went off to make war with the rest of her children, who keep the commandments of God and hold to the testimony of Jesus.

What does it mean that the earth helped the woman since it “opened its mouth”?  What is its mouth?

Comment: How one understands Rev. 12:15 depends on how one interprets the key nouns therein. The verse is, of course, metaphorical and there are several possibilities as to how στοματος ("mouth") might be understood.

Comment: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8221/in-the-song-of-moses-and-miriam-why-do-the-words-change-from-water-to-earth.You may find this helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **So shall they fear the name of the LORD from the west, and his glory
>   from the rising of the sun. When the enemy shall come in like a flood,
>   the Spirit of the LORD shall lift up a standard against him**(Isa. 59:19).

The Context for undertanding this passage is Figurative, as the "Woman" and "Dragon" are representitive of another reality, and not 'Literally' "a woman", or "a dragon".

The "Dragon", from the previous verses (vs. 3) is,

> **And there appeared another wonderb in heaven; and behold a great red
>   dragon, having seven heads and ten horns, and seven crowns upon his
>   heads.**

The "7 Head and 10 Horns" are kingdoms; we see Rev. 17:10 are kingdoms,"

> **And there are seven kings: five are fallen, and one is, and the other
>   is not yet come; and when he cometh, he must continue a short space**.

We see also that the "horns" are kingdoms also,"

> **And the ten horns which thou sawest are ten kings, which have received
>   no kingdom as yet; but receive power as kings one hour with the beast**(vs 12)

Crucial to understanding this question is understanding the "*Crowns*"; from Rev. 17:12 we see that "power is given to them for 1 hour"-obviously not "60 Minutes" but a shorter period of time, so the Crowns indicate WHO is reigning at the point of time the vision is seen. In Rev. 12 the "Head" kingdoms are reigning; in Rev. 13, the "Horn" kingdoms are reigning.

> **"And his tail drew the third part of the stars of heaven, and did cast
>   them to the earth: and the dragon stood before the woman which was
>   ready to be delivered , for to devour her child as soon as it was born
>   . 5And she brought forth a man child, who was to rule all nations with
>   a rod of iron: and her child was caught up unto God, and to his throne".**(Rev. 12:4-5)

The man-child who "rules all the nations with a rod of iron" is Christ; Ps. 2:6-9 says,"

> **Yet have I set my king upon my holy hill of Zion.   7 I will declare
>   the decree: the Lord hath said unto me, Thou art my Son; this day have
>   I begotten thee.   8 Ask of me, and I shall give thee the heathen for
>   thine inheritance, and the uttermost parts of the earth for thy
>   possession.   9 *Thou shalt break them with a rod of iron*; thou shalt
>   dash them in pieces like a potter's vessel.**

The "woman" must be understood in Figurative context, since the rest of the chapter is understood figuratively. Mary, of course, was Jesus's earthly mother, and Christ's appearance on earth was during the Roman Empire, this is described to John as a "Head that is"(Rev. 17:10," **And there are seven kings: five are fallen, and *one is."*** Satan can be seen as 'empowering' the dragon; 'red' is the color of blood. In the following verses, Satan and his angels are removed from Heaven,"

> **And the dragon was wroth with the woman, and went to make war with the
>   remnant of her seed, which keep the commandments of God, and have the
>   testimony of Jesus Christ.**(vs 17)

From this verse we see the "Woman" is more than Mary, although she is a type; "her seed" are all the believers of Jesus as the Son of God, she is "Spiritual Israel", or the 'mother' of all those who believe the promises of God,"

> **And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed
>   and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his
>   heel.**(Gen. 3:15)

It is this backround which we must lay 1st before addressing the question: "What does the earth opening it's mouth mean?"

Twice in this chapter God protects the woman by bringing her to the wilderness; the 1st time, in vs 6 she is there for 1260 days. This can be the time Mary and Joseph, who being warned by an angel, fled to Egypt(Matt. 2:14) although historians differ about the length of time, judging from the death of Herod. The distinction must be made from the "1260 days" which at least approximates the time in Egypt, to the *'time, times and a half'*, which describe a period of time, but not the same time as "*1260 days*".

The 1260 days also roughly approximate the time of Jesus's earthly ministry; since we have ascertained that the 'woman' was Spiritual Israel, she was protected, so that "**none were lost, except the son of perdition"**(John 17:12); each time there was a threat, Jesus 'withdrew to the wilderness',

> **"Jesus therefore walked no more openly among the Jews; but
>   went thence unto a country near to the wilderness, into a city called
>   Ephraim, and there continued with his disciples."**(John 11:54)

The "wilderness" was the place where God sent His prophets to encounter Him(think Elijah, Moses, John the Baptist, etc.) and also the place we encounter God. Since the "woman was given "2 wings of an eagle"(vs 14), symbolic of God's Sovereign protection,

> **"Ye have seen what I did unto the Egyptians, and how I bare you on
>   eagles' wings, and brought you unto myself.**(Ex. 19:4)

God had given the 'woman' the ability to survive the onslaught of persecution from the "Roman Empire/Antichrist nations/Beast" which came during the 1st 3 centuries of Christianity largely by preserving it's doctrinal integrity in the 'wilderness'; the Desert Fathers in Egypt, John on Patmos, the various places that Christianity(Asia Minor, Macedonia, France, Brittain, etc.) all because of the persecution that had sent the Church out of Jerusalem to the ends of the earth. Just as the "earth opened it's mouth" and prevented Herod from pursuing Joseph and Mary, so also did the earth "open it's mouth" and prevent Christianity from being destroyed at any major population center, causing instead Christianity to "flee to the wilderness" to be re-invigorated with a fresh perspective from God.

Answer (score 2):

The "earth opening it's mouth" may be linked to Numbers 16:31-32 where the Lord opened up the earth to swallow the men belonging to Korah.

> **Numbers 16:31-32** As soon as he finished saying all this, the ground under them split apart and the earth opened its mouth and
>   swallowed them and their households, and all those associated with
>   Korah, together with their possessions. (**NIV**)

Comment: Hi Kaminsky19, welcome to the BH site. Please elaborate your contribution a bit more, as the OP's question was about the meaning of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

**Most commentators regardless of wether they are preterist, historicist, symbolic or futurists take the water and the earth's mouth to be symbolic.**  However some futurists take even this literally to represent arid desert regions around Israel that will protect Christians who flee there after an invasion on Jerusalem.  Those futurists might also take the first fulfillment to be the christians fleeing the first destruction of Jerusalem by the Romans.

Forgetting one's personal bias for a moment, what is the 'mouth'? The mouth is simply an origin of something coming from, or being absorbed by, some entity. The serpent has a mouth and something is coming from it, water.  Possibly it is similar in picture to a big creature first sucking up water then turning its head and spitting it out in a torrential blast.  The earth on the other hand simply seems to act normally by absorbing the water like a sponge. **The mouth is just figurative language for all the cracks and little holes with which it is able to absorb water.**

Preterists therefore think the water in the invading Roman army attacking Israel when some Christians are believed to have escaped following the Lord's warning via the desert.  Symbolically the desert then helped absorb the attack.  Symbolic views just treat the water as whatever persecution or false doctrine against the church and via references to Exodus motifs, the desert is a dry place where God sustained the church.  Futurists can predict whatever they want as it is all in the future but will focus on a future literal Israel nation and refer to the same motifs.

My own bias in under the  historicist camp which sees the dragon as Pagan Rome fallen to the earth by the rise of Roman Christianity. The Devil subsequently sucked into his mouth Goth invaders and heretical doctrines to blast the church and in many ways succeeded as the true church became almost invisible under the wider Roman Catholic institution which rose up in her place.  This desert time of the church was basically the time where Popery was first established and strengthened until Luther. The reason for this view is the basic idea that **in prophetic literature the heavens usually represent political powers, waters are invading armies and the earth are the average people.** In this case therefore, the two wings of protection are the original east and west portions of the Roman Empire in which early Christianity was protected from paganism.  When Goths invaded Rome, they were basically absorbed into the culture of the average Roman citizen as the Roman people and the impact that true Christianity had on her, could not be totally wiped out. In other words although the ecclesiastical structure became corrupt, not every monk, or every baker and common man, denied the true gospel, so **the earth (the mass of average non powerful Roman persons) preserved early Christianity**, in spite of foreign heresies, invasions, and the resulting Christian/Pagan superstitious Roman Catholicism that was formed, to the great anger and frustration of the Devil.

Here is a good summary of this view:

> As to the fury of the flood, it was such as, throughout the length and breadth of the empire, to sweep away all the political bulwarks of Roman authority before it: and thus might well have been deemed sufficient to sweep away also the Christian Church, and Christianity itself, the professed religion of the empire. In fact the Pagan remnant, at Rome and elsewhere, were still not without their hopes of this result. The thought cheered them amidst their own sufferings; and, to accelerate it, they excited the enmity of the invaders against their Christian fellow-citizens. All showed that the spirit of the old Dragon, fallen though he was, directed the raging inundation.—But God had his own means of preserving the Church visible, and within it his true Church. The Christian,—the Trinitarian faith, had been so inwrought into the national minds and habits, as well as institutions and laws, especially from the effects of Theodosius’ reign, (for the two wings of the great eagle still helped the Woman,) that to sweep Christianity away it needed to sweep away the Roman population itself. And to effect this, though not unthought of by some of the Gothic conquerors, seemed to them not only of doubtful policy, but beyond their power. For, as the Apocalyptic figuration proceeded to foreshow, “the earth helped the woman, and swallowed up the flood.” Superstitious and earthly though the Roman population had become, yet, thus far, they did service to Christ’s Church in her present exigency. In those continuous and bloody wars of which the Western world had been the theatre, the barbarous invading population was so thinned, so absorbed, as it were, into the land they had invaded,3 that it needed their incorporation as one people with the conquered, to make up the necessary constituency of kingdoms. And, in this incorporation, not only was much of their original institutions, customs, and languages absorbed, but their religion altogether. The successive tribes, whether of Visigoths, Ostrogoths, Heruli, Huns, Vandals, Burgundians, abandoned their Paganism for Christianity.—At first indeed it was for the most part Arian pseudo-Christianity. Such was their profession in France, Spain, Africa. But, after a century or more of the flux and reflux of the invading flood, this too was abandoned for the more orthodox Trinitarian Christian faith. (Elliott, E. B. (1862). Horæ Apocalypticæ; or, A Commentary on the Apocalypse, Critical and Historical (Fifth Edition., Vol. 3, pp. 62–64). London: Seeley, Jackson, and Halliday.)

Answer (score 0):

https://endtimeprophesies.com/what-is-water-from-the-dragons-mouth-in-revelation-1215/

As there is nothing in the surrounding text of the verses to suggest symbolic interpretation I’m cautious to go to other parts of the Bible to draw conclusions as this will be in violation of Bible Hermeneutics. In the past, many Bible Scholars have rushed to interpret this verse in a symbolic way for no good reason. The reader needs to understand that we are presented here and in the surrounding verses with physical literal entities and not symbolic ones. The dragon is a physical entity, Satan himself that was thrown from heaven, the Woman=a physical entity (=the persecuted Church) that is escaping to the wilderness again a physical place on earth for survival. That leads us towards a literal rather symbolic interpretation. Of course, by doing so we are faced with a number of incredible questions that demand an answer: Is Satan manipulating physical quantities of water at the time of End? How does the earth opening its mouth and who is performing this miracle?
Interestingly there is another part in the Bible where God is performing a similar miracle to destroy Korah and his supporters and protect His Anointed Moses and Aaron, similar language is used in this passage as in Revelation 12:15: “and the earth opened its mouth and swallowed them and their households, and all those associated with Korah, together with their possessions” (Numbers 16:32)
Also, the structure of the sentence in Revelation is interesting because it says that the dragon used water LIKE a river, it doesn’t say the dragon spewed something LIKE water but rather the actual body of water is described as a river. On the other hand, in a similar passage later on in the book of Revelation where we are when later on we read about the frog like inspirations coming out of their mouths the dragon, the beast, and the false prophet we read: “Then I saw three impure spirits that looked LIKE frogs” you see these are not literal frogs because the word LIKE is preceding the word FROGS when compared with Revelation 12:15 the differences become obvious, there is no LIKE before water. The water has to be literal.

During the time of the End, dramatic changes take place in the world’s sources of water. We read in Luke 21:25: “There will be signs in the sun, moon and stars. On the earth, nations will be in anguish and perplexity at the roaring and tossing of the sea.” Also in Revelation 8:10: ” The third angel sounded his trumpet, and a great star, blazing like a torch, fell from the sky on a third of the rivers and on the springs of water” Dramatic events will take place during the last days that will affect every quantity of water and these changes will be instigated by Satan and his fallen angels.

When reading Revelation 12:15 ,16 one can not help to notice the similarities with the Exodus of the Israelites. In the same way that God used water to separate his anointed ones from Pharaoh and his army NOW in reverse order God is using the earth to swallow the waters spewed by the greater Pharaoh, Satan the dragon to save his spiritual Israelites the persecuted Church.How this will take place only time will tell

Answer (score -1):

Just like no one would say, when David was delivered from his enemies and Saul, that he was literally surrounded by cords, and waves, and snares as described in Psalm 18:4, so in Revelation 12 we should not think so literally.

So the flood the serpent pours out is probably the deceit of someone like Korah from Numbers 16, who did not want the Israelites to follow what Moses (God's chosen leader) was saying for them to do.  Notice that in Rev 12:17 the serpent goes after her children who keep the commandments of God.  Korah experienced a judgement where the earth swallowed him and his companions up.  So the Exodus motif comes into play here where God is rescuing his people from destruction.  As long as the people hold to the testimony of Jesus they will conquer the serpent (see Rev. 12:11).

See Grant Osborne's commentary on Revelation part of the Baker Exegetical Commentary Series.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here (summarize the relevant portions of the resource that answer this question), and provide the link/citation for reference. Please expand this to fully answer the question.

Answer (score -4):

The reason you do not hear many so called end time bible scholars giving a very detailed explanation of this prophecy is because the clues to it's meaning is not found in the bible but rather in the writings of the Dead Sea Scrolls For the writers of the scrolls describe false teachers and false prophets as spraying lies onto Israel. The image then of these lies is water coming from the mouth of false teachers and being spewed onto the Israelites. The waters that flow from the dragon then are the false doctrines, false gospels, and false Christs that are taught in the Church. For the woman that the dragon tries to drown is the bride of Christ, which is the Church.
Once we know what the woman and the waters represent, we can then figure out what the earth opening up represents.
The earth opening up refers to archeology, and specifically the discover of the Dead Sea Scrolls. For the Scrolls shed light on who the first Christians were. And they prove the teaching that the bible includes ALL of God's written word is a lie, in addition to many other teachings being lies from the pit of hell.

From the DSS - The Damascus Document - Genzia A Col. 1:
When the Man of Mockery appeared, who sprayed on Israel LYING WATERS, he led them to wander in the trackless wasteland.

Comment: Can you please cite the document among the DSS to which you refer? Thanks.

Comment: This answer is predominantly opinion.

Comment: To WoundedEgo; I edited my comment to include a passage from the Damascus Document, which is part of the Dead Sea Scrolls.

Comment: I agree there is good scholarship to show that the waters are symbolic of false teaching. However that does not solve the part about the earth opening its mouth. I think that's the real problem here.

Comment: I understand your skepticism. But if you accept that the waters are false teachings, false gospels and false christs being taught, and that these are designed to drown or overwhelm the bride of Christ, then we must determine what is meant by the earth opening up.and it is actually VERY important to know what is meant. Because if we get it right, we will be able to shed light on the many false doctrines and false gospels that are designed to destroy the Church from within.